# How to get data into html checkbox list, taken from javascript function call

Tags: html, checkbox, javascript

I have a page which assign some values to arrays when a function named 'hndlr' is called.code of the file is given bellow

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    var pageName = new Array();
    var pageLink = new Array();
    var pageDetails = new Array();

      function hndlr(response) {
       // here I assign values to arrays pageName,pageLink,pageDetails using a for loop     
      }

    // Some codes (I cant change anything in here)
    // call the function hndlr here (I cant change anything in here)     
    </script>     

  </body>
</html>
```

**I want to take pageName array into a checkbox list and pass the pageLink of selected checkboxes to another file.**

I tried using bellow code just before the end of the body tag. but it isn't passing any data to next page(b.php)

```
<form action="b.php" method="post">
<script>
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='formDoor[]' id='"+j+"' value= '' />"+pageName[j]+"<br />"); 
document.getElementById(j).value = pageLink[j]; 
}
</script>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I print the output, It displays 'undefined' strings just before the check boxes.
That means pageName[j] doesn't return any value.

**problem is, these arrays are not visible to second part(part I tried with check boxes)**

Please show me the way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Weird, your code is working for me (click the code box to show it): http://codepad.viper-7.com/4IVobE

You can't submit the form on this site but you can see that the arrays are accessible within the second script tag.  I also tried it on my local server and after submitting the form I was able to access the values in `b.php` just fine.

Comment: I set the valu from the second code,
document.getElementById(j).value = pageLink[j];
Problem is this arrays are not visible to second part(code I tried with the checkboxes). So when I print it, it displays 'undefined' string just after the check box. That means 'pageName[j]' doesn't return any value

Comment: Problem is these arrays are not visible to second part(code I tried with the checkboxes).

Comment: Sorry @Roshanck, I misunderstood your question the first time.  I tried your code on my local server and it works just fine for me... see the edited post above for more info.